# Use an ACAccount without saving it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

My app has tokens from Twitter and wants to make a SLRequest with them but when I do this without saving the ACAccount it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountCredential *credential = [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:@"token" tokenSecret:@"secret"];
    ACAccountType *twitterAcctType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    ACAccount *newAccount = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:twitterAcctType];
    newAccount.credential = credential;
    newAccount.username = @"username";
SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"] parameters:@{ @"screen_name" : @"username" }];
    request.account = newAccount;
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"ResponseData: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
        NSLog(@"StatusCode: %d", urlResponse.statusCode);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Log:

```
2013-06-20 00:07:55.554 MyApp[6009:c07] ResponseData: 
2013-06-20 00:07:55.555 MyApp[6009:c07] StatusCode: 0
2013-06-20 00:07:55.555 MyApp[6009:c07] Error: Error Domain=SLErrorDomain Code=0 "Could not prepare the URL request." UserInfo=0x9499020 {NSLocalizedDescription=Could not prepare the URL request.}
```

Comment: put the log for `newAccount` and check whether it contains acc details or not...let me know

Comment: Tony, this is the result of po newAccount:

Comment: $0 = 0x09c7b9f0 type:com.apple.twitter
identifier: D54E0300-7CBF-4583-A212-DEEB9BDFB6D2
accountDescription: (null)
username: ReqAccount
objectID: (null)
enabledDataclasses: {(
)}
enableAndSyncableDataclasses: {(
)}
properties: (null)
parentAccount: (null)
owningBundleID:(null)

Comment: Tony, will it otherwise be a possibility to save the account, do my requests and delete the account or isn't that save?